# Buttons on custom uitableview cell disappearing

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

So I have a custom `uitableviewcell` that uses `iCarousel` to load another view. That view loses it's `buttons`. I can't see the buttons and I can click on them, but when I do there is an exception. I think this is a memory issue.

This is how I'm creating the view -

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(OptionView *)view
{
    if (view == nil)
    {
        view = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"OptionView" owner:view options:nil] lastObject];
    }
    NSDictionary* option = [self.options objectAtIndex:index];
    view.imageUrl = option[@"ImageUrl"];
    view.option = option[@"Option"];
    view.currentPage = option[@"Page"];
    view.page = view.currentPage;
    view.postAs = self.postingAs;
    [view init];
    return view;
}
```

Why am I getting the error I am getting?

```
-(id)init{
    self = [super init];
    self.upVotesLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", self.upVotes];
    self.downVotesLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",self.downVotes];
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);

    NSString* photoUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.imageUrl];
    self.optionImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"trending.png"];
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: photoUrl]];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        self.optionImageView.image = image;
    });


    return self;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line at the end [view init], it initializes the view again.

Comment: er so I have a custom init method - I'll post that up

Comment: Put it [view init] just after the if statement. if (view == nil)
    {
        view = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"OptionView" owner:view options:nil] lastObject];} [view init];

Answer (score 0):

if you load the view in nib. do the init in `awakeFromNib`

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    self.upVotesLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", self.upVotes];
    self.downVotesLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",self.downVotes];
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);

    NSString* photoUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.imageUrl];
    self.optionImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"trending.png"];
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: photoUrl]];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        self.optionImageView.image = image;
    });
}
```